# PhoneGap Build - Could not get unknown property 'GMS_VERSION' for object of type org.gradle

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

From one day to another my build is now failing and these are the logs I have got from phonegap build:

```
Total time: 2.61 secs
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
"plugman-151 install --platform android --project /project --plugin cordova-plugin-splashscreen --nohooks=.": Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" at "5.0.2" for android
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
null

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/project/build.gradle' line: 253

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'project'.
> Could not get unknown property 'GMS_VERSION' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.853 secs
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-splashscreen': Error: /project/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/project/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
/project/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1
```

I thought there was a problem with the splashscreen plugin so I downgrade it and then removed it but then the builds keeps failing complaining about another plugin with basically the same error.
I don't know much about the Gradle file and from my understanding PhoneGap Build takes care of it or at least it should handle it.

I am using Phonegap-cli 6.4 and the build is for Android.

Please guys let me know if you need further info to help and THANKS a lot :)

UPDATE: The only way to get a successful build is removing all the plugins from the config.xml :'( :'( :'(...and now? Still trying to figure out another way to add the plugins then.

UPDATE 2: These are the logs if I use Phonegap-Cli 7.0.1

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
COMPILE OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:wrapper

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
null
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
    at build_3165fehnqtadtl3m714hg3us5.run(/build.gradle:138)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/build.gradle' line: 253

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'www_android'.
> Could not get unknown property 'GMS_VERSION' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.08 secs
Error: /gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/build.gradle' line: 253

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'www_android'.
> Could not get unknown property 'GMS_VERSION' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
```

Similar error - no clue whats going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a a successful build deleting this line in my config.xml

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-google-analytics" source="npm" />
```

Maybe there is a problem with this plugin...

good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot, weirdly enough removing that plugin fixed the build :)
Since I actually needed that plugin, I have looked for a compatible version and I have downgraded the version from the latest (1.8.6) to 1.8.4 and it is still working :)

    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-google-analytics"          spec="1.8.4"/>